# (JS) Transform array of objects with path to nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom, tree

I need to transform array of objects with path like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    path:['A'],
    label:"A1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    path:['AA'],
    label:"AA1"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    path:['A', 'B', 'C'],
    label:"ABC1"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    path:['A', 'B'],
    label:"AB1"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    path:['A', 'B', 'C'],
    label:"ABC2"
  }
]
```

to something like tree:

```
[
  {
    key:'A', //current path
    children:[ // childrens of current path
      {
        id: 1,
        path:['A'],
        label:"A1"
      },
      {
        key:'B',
        children: [
          {
            id: 4,
            path:['A', 'B'],
            label:"AB1"
          },
          {
            key:"C",
            children:[
              {
                id: 3,
                path:['A', 'B', 'C'],
                label:"ABC1"
              },
              {
                id: 5,
                path:['A', 'B', 'C'],
                label:"ABC2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'AA',
    children:[
      {
        id: 2,
        path:['AA'],
        label:"AA1"
      },
     ]
  }
]
```

i need this for create nested collapse menu.
something like

- A

  - ...items of a
  - B

    - ...items of b
    - C

      - ...items of c
- AA

  - ...items of AA

thx in advance, i know it not so hard question but still have some problems with this(
Or if i do something bad or is more good way to do that, please reply i will be happy for all help)

Comment: Why is `id:2` in the output for `key: 'AA'` while `key:'A'` doesn't have the `id`? And `path` property is removed if an object has `children`?

Comment: @adiga , sorry my bad(, updated question.

Comment: @adiga i want to add like, key: ...all items on that path. Or it's bad(?.
I other case, i will cannot map this to collapse menu, i need path and childrens that are in this path

Comment: Your input data has 5 labels, but your output only has 3. Your input has 5 paths and 5 ids, but the output only has 4 of each. What is the logic behind that?

Comment: @trincot no, again sorry(. didn't notice it. updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```js
var data = [{'id': 1, 'path': ['A'], 'label': 'A1'}, {'id': 2, 'path': ['AA'], 'label': 'AA1'}, {'id': 3, 'path': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'label': 'ABC1'}, {'id': 4, 'path': ['A', 'B'], 'label': 'AB1'}, {'id': 5, 'path': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'label': 'ABC2'}]
function to_tree(d){
   var new_d = {}
   for (var i of d){
      var k = i._path.shift()
      if (!(k in new_d)){
         new_d[k] = []
      }
      new_d[k].push(i)
   }
   return Object.keys(new_d).map(function(x){
        var _pl = {0:[], 1:[]}
        for (var i of new_d[x]){
           _pl[i._path.length > 0 ? 1 :0].push(i)
        }
        return {key:x, children:[..._pl[0].map(function(j){
               delete j['_path']
               return j
           }), to_tree(_pl[1])]}
    });
}
var new_data = data.map(function(x){return {...x, '_path':JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x.path))}})
console.log(to_tree(new_data))
```

Output:

```
[{'key': 'A', 'children': [{'id': 1, 'path': ['A'], 'label': 'A1'}, [{'key': 'B', 'children': [{'id': 4, 'path': ['A', 'B'], 'label': 'AB1'}, [{'key': 'C', 'children': [{'id': 3, 'path': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'label': 'ABC1'}, {'id': 5, 'path': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'label': 'ABC2'}, []]}]]}]]}, {'key': 'AA', 'children': [{'id': 2, 'path': ['AA'], 'label': 'AA1'}, []]}]
```

Comment: @Denis Glad to help!